# How to change the yaw angle in ROS

Tags: ros, yaw, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I have been working on the ar.drone flying robot and what I want is to have the ar.drone takeoff, change the yaw angle by 90 degrees while holding that hover position and then land. I tried to write some code to achieve this but what happens is the ar.drone keeps on spinning all throughout the take off and landing. Here is my method:

```
void DC::Yaw(){
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Publisher flyF = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/cmd_vel", 1000, true);
    geometry_msgs::Twist yaw;
 
    yaw.angular.x =0;
    yaw.angular.y = 0;
    yaw.angular.z = 1.57;

    flyF.publish(yaw);
    ros::Duration(1).sleep();  
}
```

My takeoff and land functions work well but it is just this yaw function that is causing me issues.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90031/how-to-change-the-yaw-angle-in-ros/) by [MichaelJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/6706/michaelj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-10-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-12**:
What if you publish zero velocity after that 1 second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try resetting the linear velocities to zeros when you want to hover?

---

Originally posted by [espee](https://answers.ros.org/users/6531/espee/) with karma: 81 on 2013-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/6706/michaelj/) on 2013-10-12**:
Should I also set the yaw.angular.z back to zero?

**Comment by [espee](https://answers.ros.org/users/6531/espee/) on 2013-10-12**:
if you just want a takeoff, rotation and land, your twist sequence should look sth like [0 0 1 0 0 0] (1m/s z-direction) [0 0 0 0 0 1] (1 rad/s along z-axis) [0 0 -1 0 0 0] (-1m/s z-direction) and finally [0 0 0 0 0 0].